# Assigning a unit type to a variable

Tags: kotlin

**What happens if you assign a a `Unit` type to a variable in Kotlin?**

Lets use this small piece of code as an example:

```
val list = listOf("Hey", "this", "code", "runs")
val unit = list.forEach {
    print(it.plus(" "))
}
```

Output:

> Hey this code runs

Why does this code run? What is the value of `val unit` in this example? I mean, shoudn't there be a `unit.invoke()` function to actually run the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the basis of operators, first right side operand is executed and its value is returned to left side operator. So how can you expect that you will store that function in a variable and then call it using variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin, [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html) is a type that has exactly one value: the object also called `Unit`.

It has the same purpose as the `void` type in Java, but the implementation is different.  (This is because Kotlin borrows ideas from functional languages, in which every expression has a value.  So if a function has nothing useful to return, it returns `Unit` instead.  This distinguishes it from methods that *never* return, declared with the `Nothing` type which has *no* values.)

Your code is perfectly valid; the `forEach()` executes and prints its output, and then returns the `Unit` value afterward.  (`forEach()` is one of those functions you call *only* for its side-effects, not for its return value.  That's why you don't usually bother doing anything with the return value; but you've shown that you can if you really want to!)

So your `unit` is inferred to have the type `Unit`, and will be assigned the `Unit` value.

You could check this by printing it afterward:

```
println(unit)
```

That prints "`kotlin.Unit`", which is the result of calling `toString()` on the `Unit` value.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this code run?

It makes semantically and syntactically sence for the language Kotlin. Both initialisations of your variables are return values of the functions in front of them.

-

> What is the value of val unit in this example?

*unit* is `Unit` - [like `void` in Java](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html) - because [foreach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) returns `Unit`

```
val unit : Unit = list.forEach {
    print(it.plus(" "))
}
```

-

> shoudn't there be a unit.invoke() function to actually run the code?

The varible *unit* is initialised with the execution of `forEach`. To get the result it invokes the loop, which executes `print(it.plus(" "))` .

### EDIT

> What happens if you assign a a Unit type to a variable in Kotlin?

Nothing. There is no need to save/store it.